# Finding the coordinates of the vertices of an equilateral triangle.

Tags: geometry, systems-of-equations, polar-coordinates

I have an equilateral triangle.

1. I know the orientation of that triangle(that means I know the angle 
   of one of the sides of the triangle with respect to the origin).
2. I know the coordinates of the midpoint of the same base of the triangle
3. I know the length of the sides.

How Do I find the points of the vertices ? 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hint:$(x,y)$ is the midpoint of the triangle.

Comment: I tried a lot to find the answer. Couldn't do it. Could you please give me an answer ?

Answer (score 0):

**As you could not solve it from my first hint I am giving an example of a simillar problem to help you.**

[image]

*Hope it will be clear after this.I uploaded the picture and not typed it out as it is very very tiring to write out the whole program code for this,as you may understand.Please don't mind.*